# Scala constructor abstraction

Tags: scala, polymorphism

The following is possible in Scala:

```
scala> val l = List
l: scala.collection.immutable.List.type = scala.collection.immutable.List$@7960c21a

scala> l ( 1, 2, 3 )
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

In other words, Scala has higher-order polymorphism. I would like to use higher-order polymorphism to do the following.

```
sealed abstract class A { def eval () : A }
case class A0 () extends A { ... }
case class A1 ( a : A ) extends A { ... }
case class A2 ( a : A, b : A ) extends A { ... }
....
```

So I have a bunch of case classes, subclasses of `A`, whose constructors don't necessarily take the same numbers of arguments. I also would like to have a 'generic' case class, something like this:

```
case class ApplyA ( c : ???, l : List [ A ] ) extends A {
   def eval () : A = { ??? } }
```

The idea is that `ApplyA` takes as first argument a constructor for something that is a subtype of `A`, and a list of arguments. The `eval` method then constructs an appropriate class with the constructor if possible (i.e. the list has the right length) and returns it
(this corresponds to `l ( 1, 2, 3)` in the `List` example above). What would be the type of the argument of the first constructor for `ApplyA`?

This should be possible with higher-order polymorphism, but I could not work out how. I know that I can do this even without using higher-order polymorphism by simply wrapping constructors in functions and then passing these functions as first argument to the constructor for `ApplyA`, but I'd like to understand how to use higher-order polymorphism directly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that the `List` example doesn't involve any higher-order polymorphism at all. `List.apply` just takes a variable number of parameters:

```
def apply(xs: A*)
```

Higher-order polymorphism involves methods, or types, which take type constructors as type parameters, e.g.

```
def fmap[F[_], A](x: F[A]): F[B]
```

So no, you can't do it using higher-order polymorphism.

Answer (score 13):

@alexey_r is quite right that your `List` example doesn't involve higher-order polymorphism. But if you're prepared to use some [type-level heavy artillery](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) you can abstract over the arity of your `A{0,1,2}` constructors to get something that looks quite close to what you're asking for.

The first point to note is that, as written, your 'generic' class can't possibly be implemented,

```
case class ApplyA(c : ???, l : List[A]) ...
```

because there's no compile time checkable relationship between the arity of the constructor `c` and the length of the list `l`. We can fix that problem by replacing the `List` with an `HList` and helping ourselves to a conversion from ordinary functions with arbitrary arity to functions with a single `HList` argument,

```
import shapeless.HList._
import shapeless.Functions._

sealed abstract class A { def eval() : A }
case class A0 () extends A { def eval() = this }
case class A1 ( a : A ) extends A  { def eval() = this }
case class A2 ( a : A, b : A ) extends A  { def eval() = this }

case class ApplyA[C, L <: HList, HF](c : C, l : L)
  (implicit hl : FnHListerAux[C, HF], ev : HF <:< (L => A)) extends A {
    def eval () : A = hl(c)(l)
  }

val a : A = A0()

val a0 = ApplyA(A0.apply _, HNil)
val a1 = ApplyA(A1.apply _, a :: HNil)
val a2 = ApplyA(A2.apply _, a :: a :: HNil)
```

The implicit argument `hl : FnHListerAux[C, HF]` provides a conversion from your constructor, whatever it's arity, to a function from a single HList argument. And the implicit argument `ev : HF <:< (L => A)` witnesses that the length of the supplied `HList` of constructor arguments is of the correct length (and types FWIW, but that's barely relevant in this example).